# In C#, how to make my custom Attribute only attachable to classes derived from certain class?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a class like this

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AbilityTemplateAttribute  {
    }
```

It makes

> Error CS0641 Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute

How can I make my own Attribute work similarly, that is, does not allow to be attached to classes not inherited from a certain class?

Comment: Why can't you inherit from System.Attribute?

Comment: You probably can't. I expect that that behaviour of that particular attribute is built into the compiler rather than the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know of to have similar behaviour with custom attribute is to write custom Roslyn analyzer. If your are ok going down this route here some documentation:

- [Getting Started Writing a Custom Analyzer & Code Fix](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix.md)
- [How to write a Roslyn Analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/)
- [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)